# How can I automatically rewrite the signature of bindgen-created FFI functions?

Tags: binding, rust, ffi

I'm writing a binding for a C library with the help of `rust-bindgen` for which the function signatures are generated automatically into a `bindings.rs` as:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct A {
    //...
}

struct B {
    //...
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn foo(x: *mut A, y: *mut B);
    //...
}
```

I'm not very happy with this signature of `foo` because I know that `x` is a pointer to a constant struct. Moreover, I want to apply [this idea](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/stateful-closure-for-ffi-callback/29339/2) to improve this signature into something like

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn foo(x: &'_ A, y: &'_ mut B);
}
```

But `binding.rs` has a bunch functions like `foo` and rewriting them by hand is a very time consuming task and I think that macros (or something else) should help. For example, there might exist one (or several) magic macro `rewrite!`

```rust
// hide
mod ffi {
    include!("binding.rs"); // so bunch of functions: foo, bar
}

// re-exports
extern "C" {
    rewrite!(foo); // should expand to: pub fn foo(x: &'_A, y: &'_ mut B)
    rewrite!(bar);
}
```

I'm at a very early stage of this work. I don't even know if such a problem can be solved by a macro or anything else, so I'm looking for any entry point.

I've [cross-posted this question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/reexport-auto-generated-ffi-functions-by-macros/29650) to the Rust user forum.

Comment: Why not writing a wrapper for it?

Comment: @hellow thanks you. Could you elaborate a little bit? Sorry for my novice.

Answer (score 1):

A declarative macro can't accomplish this but a procedural macro might be able to. With [`proc_macro2`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2), you can modify the token stream of a function declaration by placing your rewrite attribute on it, e.g.

```rust
extern "C" {
    #[rustify]
    pub fn foo(x: *mut A, y: *mut B);
}
```

And your `rustify` macro would substitute `*mut Typename` with `Option<&mut Typename>`.

I don't know how you'd change the `mut` borrow offhand without replacing the original declaration with `*const`.

Comment: *With proc_macro2* — it's not **required** to use this crate, it's just one of the most common methods to interact with a token stream.

Comment: @myrrlyn thanks you. I'm not familiar with `proc_macro2` yet, but thanks a lot for the entry point.